# How can I stop a div inside a modal from moving on mouse hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal with shortcut icons inside it, the code can be seen below. The problem is that whenever I hover over one of the icons the one below shifts downwards with no apparent changes in the actual HTML (viewed through the browser inspector)

```
<!-- SHORTCUTS MODAL BEGINS -->
  <div id="shortcuts" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="shortcuts" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="twelve columns">
              <h2 id="modalTitle">Shortcuts</h2>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row list-icon">
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-tasks"></i><span class="label">Course</span> → [SHIFT] + [C]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-user"></i><span class="label">Profile</span> → [ALT] + [P]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-share"></i><span class="label">Shortcuts</span> → [SHIFT] + [?]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-home"></i><span class="label">Home</span> → [SHIFT] + [H]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-lock"></i><span class="label">Admin</span> → [SHIFT] + [A]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-laptop"></i><span class="label">Portfolio</span> → [SHIFT] + [P]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-envelope"></i><span class="label">Email</span> → [SHIFT] + [E]
        </div>
        <div class="six columns">
            <i class="icon-comment"></i><span class="label">Contact</span> → [SHIFT] + [K]
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="close-reveal-modal"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
  </div> 
  <!-- SHORTCUTS MODAL ENDS -->
```

I've been googling this issue for a while to no avail.

Picture representation of the issue if I hover over 'Course'

[image]

The css for each icon class is very simple

```
.icon-tasks:before {
content: "\f0ae";
}
```

I tried disable hover by adding this class also but it didn't work

```
.noHover{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Share also your CSS or a complete working example

Comment: have you tried to remove hover form it ?

Comment: please see updated question, if you need any more info let me know please @MarcosPérezGude  and fernando

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this issue I solved it by adding pointer-events: none to the CSS for the entire Row as opposed to for each individual button.

tl;dr I am useless with CSS and this barely warranted a question.